# How to pass parameters from one view to another view?

Tags: php, laravel

**shirt.blade.php:**

```
@extends('layout.main')
@section('title','Shirts') 

@section('content')

<div class="row">

    @forelse($shirts->chunk(20) as $chunk)
    @foreach($chunk as $shirt)
    <div class="small-3 columns">
        <div class="item-wrapper">
            <div class="item2">
                <div class="img-wrapper">
                    <a href="{{route('cart.addItem',$shirt->id)}}"  class="button expanded add-to-cart">
                        <span title = "To Add to cart directly">Add to Cart </span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="{{url('images',$shirt->image)}}"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <a href="{{url('/shirt.$shirt->id')}}">
                    <h3>
                        {{$shirt->name}}
                    </h3>
                </a>
                <h5>
                    ${{$shirt->price}}
                </h5>
                <p>
                    {{$shirt->description}}
                </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @endforeach
        @empty
        <h3>No Shirts</h3>
        @endforelse
    </div>
    <br>
```

> I am passing $shirt->id parameter

```
</div>
<a href="{{url('/shirt.$shirt->id')}}">
<h3>
    {{$shirt->name}}
</h3>
```

This is my Controller from where I am passing `id`.Named by **FrontController.php**

```
public function shirt($id) {
    $shirt = Product::all();
    return view('front.shirt', compact('shirt')
            ->with('id' => '$id');
    }
}
```

How can I pass id from view **shirts.blade.php** to view **shirt.blade.php**

Please help.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this:

Change blade file code and controller code like

```
<a href="{{url('/shirt', $shirt->id)}}">
    <h3>
       {{$shirt->name}}
    </h3> 


public function shirt($id){
    $id = $id;
    $shirt = Product::all();
   return view('front.shirt',
compact('shirt','id');
}
```

### Updated answer

Change from `shirts.blade.php` code

```
<a href="{{url('shirt', $shirt->id)}}">

    <h3>
        {{$shirt->name}}
    </h3>
</a>
```

**TO**

```
<?php print('<pre style="color:red;">');
  print_r($shirt->id);
  print('</pre>');
  exit; ?>

<a href="{{ route('shirt', [$shirt->id]) }}">

    <h3>
        {{$shirt->name}}
    </h3>
</a>
```

Comment: @Faiez Any link not open

Comment: @Faiez All link have same issue?

Comment: @Faiez  Because $shirt->id not get in this url

Comment: that what i looking for that $shirt->id will be shown automatically in the url and we don't need to give this manually

Comment: @Faiez just check my updated answer we can trace $shirt->id

Comment: Sorry Sir, I am not getting id either in page nor in console.

Comment: @Faiez Thats the reason your url not work because in url have no any id

Comment: @Faiez Wait a minute

Comment: @Faiez This link in localhost:8000/shirts instead of localhost:8000 so please check in localhost:8000/shirts

Comment: Yes, I am getting the shirts id.

Comment: Okay Brother.Its working perfect. Thanks a lot. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function shirt($id){
   $this_id = $id;
   $shirt = Product::all();
   return view('front.shirt',
   compact('shirt','this_id');
  }
 }
```